# lua ZeroBrane Studio failed to initialize lua511.dll not found

Tags: lua, zerobrane

First time user of Lua and installed version 5.3.5 then tried to install the IDE - ZeroBrane  Studio.

Unfortunately when I start ZeroBrane Studio it says the following:

> Failed to initialize editor
>   The lua511.dll could not be found or loaded, please check the working directory of the application.

Comment: Lua 5.11 is not released yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is something completely wrong, as there is no `lua511.dll`, only `lua51.dll`, and I can find no references to `lua511.dll` anywhere in the project or generated binary files.

If you are launching the IDE using `zbstudio.exe`, you can also try launching it using `bin\lua src\main.lua` command to see if it makes any difference. You can also try launching `bin\lua` to see if it launches (as it depends on the same `lua51.dll` library).

If you are launching it using a shortcut, then check its "Properties" and set "Start in" to the location where you installed the IDE (the location of zbstudio.exe file).

Comment: I am used to working with products that install and just work.  So I did struggle but finally got lua53.dll installed as that is the latest so that makes sense.  Now I need an IDE and Zero Brane was considered the best.  I went to download page and click on the Windows 32 bit EXE and let it install where it wants to.

Comment: Update now I specified that I want it installed in c:\dev\zerobrane and vola, it works!  Wow, who would have thought it was that simple to fix.  Problem solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As my experience, I have never seen a lua511.dll and if it says that then there must be something wrong with your program.

There should only be a lua51.dll, although if you'd like, you can just rename it to lua511.dll but there should be a more professional fix towards it.

As this just may be a grammar issue, make sure your lua51.dll is actually there, or if it might be in the wrong directory. If it's in the right directory or if its there then do reinstall it with common troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Sorry new user, ok the error message states lua51.dll (not 511).  I just started with Lua and have to say it is a pain to install on Win 10.  What I have is lua53.dll as that is the latest.  So why does Zero Brane not accept the latest version and instead looks for lua51.dll?  How can I get this to work?